# Getting `thread_ts` from `reaction_added` event in Slack API

Tags: slack-api

The use-case is as follows: When user adds a reaction to a message within a thread the Slack bot needs to reply in the same thread.

The problem is that `reaction_added` event type does not contain the `thread_ts` which would allow to identify the thread (nor the `ts` of the root message, which is the same AFAIU).

Is there a way to resolve the thread of the message to which `reaction_added` was sent to?

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, `reaction_added` event doesn't have parent ts (thread_ts).

Instead, you can call `conversations_replies` API with any `ts` including the on in the `reaction_added` event. It will return an one-length replies list, containing the ts you sent. **This has `thread_ts` of the thread!**

This means that you can find the parent thread_ts with double `conversations_replies` like below code:

```py
# python3 example

def get_root_message(ts, channel, need_thread_ts=False):
    resp = client.conversations_replies(ts=ts, channel=channel)
    first_msg = resp["messages"][0]
    if not need_thread_ts:
        return first_msg
    return get_root_message(first_msg["thread_ts"], channel, need_thread_ts=False)


root_msg = get_root_message(ts=(reaction_added_event["item"]["ts"]),
                       channel=(reaction_added_event["item"]["channel"]),
                       need_thread_ts=True)

print(root_msg["thread_ts"])
```

It seems a bit inefficient but works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The test payloads I tried for that event had

```
.event.item.ts
```

and

```
.event.item.channel
```

in them.

https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added

Comment: Yes, but channels and threads are not the same. Channels are top-level elements, while message threads are inner replies to a message. Channel info seems to be available, while thread info is not.

Comment: > `.event.item.ts` – this seems to point to the message to which the reaction was added, but not the root message of the thread (if I understand correctly)

Comment: Ok, I see what you are after.  

The chat.getPermalink method returns a URL that always contains the parent message ts but will return a slightly different one for a threaded reply.

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.getPermalink